# secondary domain controller did not authenticate users after primary DC went down

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012

Secondary DC did not authenticate users after primary DC went down and Once I get this critical error in secondary dns on secondary dc after pdc down Directly.

Event ID 4015
( The DNS server has encountered a critical error from the Active Directory. Check that the Active Directory is functioning properly. The extended error debug information (which may be empty) is . The event data contains the error.)

Comment: Is your PDC running SBS?

Answer (score 0):

Check DNS client configuration on second controller:

- If in domain multiple DCs that’s the DNS servers are in a domain
  environment, recommendation to have all DCs point to ANOTHER/REMOTE
  DC’s IP address as preferred DNS and *then point to it’s private IP
  address as an alternate DNS*.

When first controller crush, DNS client on second needs new DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NLTEST` command from client to check if computer is connected to domain